# Clear form fields after a successful submit

Tags: php, html, forms

well im working on a small html form.

```
            <form class="contact" action="" method="POST">
                <label>Name : </label><input type="text" name="name" value="<? echo $name; ?>"/>
                <p class="middle"><label>Comment : </label><textarea name="message"></textarea><? echo $message; ?></p>
                <label class="captcha"><img src="captcha.php" style="line-height: 30px;"></label><input type="text" name="code"/>
                <input type="submit" class="csubmit" value="Now !" name="get"/>
            </form>
```

and this is the php code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['get'])) {
    $error = "";
    if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    } else {
    $error .= "no name. <br />";
    }


    if (!empty($_POST['message'])) {
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    } else {
    $error .= "no message <br />";
    }

    if(($_POST['code']) == $_SESSION['code']) { 
  $code = $_POST['code'];
  } else { 
  $error .= "wrong captcha <br />";    
}
    if (!empty($error)) {
      echo '<p class="error">Error :<br/>' . $error . '</p>';
      } elseif (!empty($success)) {
      echo $success;
      }

    if (empty($error)) {
        $message = mysql_real_escape_string($message);
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments(id, name, comment, time,approved)VALUES('$id', '$name', '$message', '$date', '0')");
   echo "thank you";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

As you can see i user $message and $name to keep informations after a submit with wrong captcha code, but the problem is that i want to clear those fields after a submit with correct informations. Can you please tell me how can i clear form fields after a succesfull submit ?

Comment: how about doing a header() call  to the form  once the data is submitted successfully

Comment: header("Location:your-file-name");  should be the exact code

Comment: Sorry but the user should see an succes message on the same page before redirecting him !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use .reset() on your form.

```
$("#form")[0].reset();
```

You could follow that with Javascript too

```
document.getElementById('form').reset();
```

Or, if successful, redirect the user back to your contact page:

```
header("Location: contact.php"); // redirect back to your contact form
exit;
```

**EDIT**

```
<input type="submit" class="csubmit" value="Now !" name="get" onClick="clearform();" />

function clearform()
{
    document.getElementById("name").value=""; //don't forget to set the textbox ID
    document.getElementById("message").value=""; //don't forget to set the textbox ID
    document.getElementById("code").value=""; //don't forget to set the textbox ID
}
```

Also use:

```
required="required"
```

so people will be required to fill out the input fields :)

Which by the way is the prefered method. If you keep the user in a page that was reached through a POST method, if he refreshes the page the form will be submitted again.

Comment: Srry but the user should see a successful message befor redirection !

Comment: You could redirect to a thank you page and have that thank you page redirect back to your contact form lol Or let me think of something else

Comment: Take your time please help !

Comment: quick question: is the message showing up right now? So all you need to do is reset the form?

Comment: Updated the post... please check

Comment: but what if the user doesnt enter a correct captcha ? in this case  the fields should be not cleard

Comment: !@user check my last msg

Comment: Not much you can do there... Usually people use the header location function and use echo to display the success message. This is a great javascript solution I posted and it wouldn't hurt for them to refill 2 fields again if they enter the wrong code.

Comment: I have a long forms :( there's no solutions ?

Comment: Uhmmm honestly, one more solution... but very insecure... you can have a hidden input field with value as your $_SESSION['code']...  Then you could compare that to the captcha fields value entered